# MySQL correct setup for csv data upload

Tags: mysql

I have a csv file with data for dates, for many unique CU units.

Each day, there will be more systems added, with Temp and Volt readings.

This is how the data currently looks in a csv file:

```
CU      Parameters    01-02-2017    02-02-2017  03-02-2017
379-H   Temp               8           9        10
379-H   Voltage            12.1        12.2     12.1
101-A   Temp               7           6        5
101-A   Voltage            12.3        12.1     12.3
```

Would this be the most efficient way to upload to mysql? (Option 1):

```
Date           CU        Temp     Voltage
2017-02-01     379-H     8         12.1
2017-02-01     101-A     7         12.3
```

Or this (Option 2):

```
CU         date         temp          voltage
379-H    2017-02-01       8              12.1
101-A    2017-02-01       7              12.3
```

I'm sure Option 2 is the answer, but since I have nearly a 1000 unique CU values, I'm not sure the format of the csv data lends itself to being uploaded in this way...

Comment: I don't get the difference between these 2 options. You just swapped column or you meant that first will be PK?

Comment: I don't see a difference between your two options.  As to how you pivot the date from columns to rows is another story.

Answer (score 0):

You can store it as `json` in a JSON type field:

Something like:

```
{
      {
        'date' : '01-02-2017' 
        'CU' : '379-H',
        'temp': 8,
        'voltage': 12.1
      },
      {
        'date' : '02-02-2017' 
        'CU' : '101-A',
        'temp': 4,
        'voltage': 12.4
      }  
}
```

and so on..